# conditional types not getting excluded from result

Tags: typescript

I have created [this playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=44&pc=1#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBMAdgVwLZwCpQIaIM4Bm0qwUAggMYwCWE+cA3gFBxwAiwANsDMHALxwA5ABMuPYEIA0TAL5MmMAJ5g+AMWqdeUYCIDSwJXgA8GKXACqAPgGM4AbQAKcaojgBrQxAKYAugC5MJ18EEF5EETwPLx8sXEJiUkoaOiiAfjhEYAA3UjhAjGDQ8MjLOAznQKzcqDhZe08lbz8AbgVlVTg1N0EACgA6QewoAHM8QNwle18ASgEbSbamUEhYOA6+OPwiKBIRYwBlcwBZG0FmVicXNw0tUl0DI0OTqwC4A6LQEqju8rgAJR4yCgiAwKmAh2CNiqOVIbVkS2W4Gg8AoqXgEAARgArYBUY7YMCqWqCZ5wY6sL5IUpbBK7XRk05WXosVhwPAQYEUYCBI6s1ioQmBY5MGYFHDbRL7I7ks42BhwflwHQwYFuBiyODYKKYCV0vaMqxyBRo-DwDlcvjnJUEahQPAwABy2BIgSEjmwyE40iVeDVLp5wgAwhAAO64H1srUjQMAVgADDIo9gRCIdHhxsIOSRQwALe7XTJh-M6IRyJYbd6cqDc2wbZoWmvAE3ouCCsC2C5slNp4AZ8XxHYkchUWj4focbi8JNsxABwK9RC86vcub8GwAAwAJAxEP1bfanQHNTu936QceN8amKaHcq+174IIsbj8YTib1G9zzO2ZgoAPQAFTsrmnKcCIcCYnwTBdnOrrsjAUCuCM14AJJwCIdBCPAMC5q47hwLadxIYgIxwHQCAoOg1BRJAGbUJi3CQcg8CIBA5rAnweZKOs+YAkCIJgp0NFFvAobQO4yFMIB-5MEAA) that illustrates the problem and here is the code:

```js
export enum TransformerActions {
  Delete = 'delete',
}

type FilteredKeys<T, U> = { [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends keyof TransformerActions ? never : T[P] extends U ? P : never }[keyof T];

type Fn = (...args: any[]) => any;

export type Transformed<S, M> = {
  [P in FilteredKeys<S, M>]: S[P] extends Fn ? ReturnType<S[P]> : never;
};


export const objectMapper = <S, M  extends Transformed<S, M>>(
    source: S,
    map: M
): Transformed<S, M> => { 
  const result: TransformerMap<S> = {};

  for (const k of Object.keys(source)) {
    if(!map[k]) {
      continue;
    }
    
    const value = source[k];

    if (map?.[k] === TransformerActions.Delete) {
      continue;
    }

    if (typeof map?.[k] === 'function') {
      result[k] = transform(map[k](source));;
      continue;
    }

    result[k] = value;
  }

  return result;
}

const source = {
    firstName: 'Paul',
    surname: 'Cowan',
    age: 50,
    address: 'somewhere in nowhere'
};

type Source = typeof source

const map = {
    address: TransformerActions.Delete,
    name: (n: Source) => `${n.firstName} ${n.surname}`
}

const result = objectMapper(source, map)

/* should be 
{
  name: string
}

I don't think filtering on enum is possible but not sure why the ReturnType is not working
*/
```

Basically I have an `objectTransformer` function and I want to use conditional types to filter out all fields that return a specific enum or if the field is a function then I want that field to return the `ReturnType` of the function and not the function itself

```js
const map = {
    address: TransformerActions.Delete,
    name: (n: Source) => `${n.firstName} ${n.surname}`
}
```

Neither condition is working for me right now :).

Comment: I don't fully get what you are trying to do - in the `map` ojbect you pass to your objectMapper - what about `firstName` and `surName`? should they exist in the `result` object? if no - then what's the purpose of `TransformerActions.Delete`? just omit the keys. explaining this will help to give a working solution...  in the more general sense, one of the issues is the `FilteredKeys` type, you do conditional on T[P] when you need U[P]. So you first need to understand/explain better the relation between the map keys and the source object keys

Comment: @AviadHadad I've added a brief outline of what the function does.  Let me know if I can clarify it any more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this is what you mean, I'm still not clear on why you need `TransformerActions.Delete` if just omitting a key from the map object gets the same result... but I guess you maybe have a specific use case and you tried to give an example here. Again, I hope this is what you meant -

```js
export enum TransformerActions {
  Delete = 'delete',
}

 /** takes an type like {foo: number, bar: never} returns type {foo: number}  */
type RemoveNever<T> = Pick<T, { [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends never ? never : K }[keyof T]>;

type Fn<T> = (arg: T) => any; 
type ObjectMap<S> = Record<string, Fn<S> | TransformerActions> 

type Transformed_Stage1<S, M extends ObjectMap<S>> = {
  [P in keyof M]: M[P] extends Fn<S> ?
    ReturnType<M[P]> :
    M[P] extends TransformerActions.Delete ?
      never :
      never;
}

/** split Transformed just for clarity sake, you can probably write this in one type decleration */
export type Transformed<S, M extends ObjectMap<S>> = RemoveNever<Transformed_Stage1<S, M>>;


export const objectMapper = <S, M  extends ObjectMap<S>>(
    source: S,
    map: M
): Transformed<S, M> => { 
    return {} as  Transformed<S, M>
}

const source = {
    firstName: 'Paul',
    surname: 'Cowan',
    age: 50,
    address: 'somewhere in nowhere'
};

type Source = typeof source

const map = {
    address: TransformerActions.Delete,
    name: (n: Source) => `${n.firstName} ${n.surname}`
}

const result = objectMapper(source, map);

/* only result.name autocompletes */
result.name
```